# Looping an mp3 in android studio using kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to loop my mp3 in kotlin. I know in java you can simply do it using .setLooping(true) method but its not available in kotlin for me..

i tried doing .isLooping() but that just seems to return a Boolean type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For *Kotlin*

```
mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
```

becomes

```
mediaPlayer.isLooping = true
```